# Unable to find module trying to create Database using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Learning how to use MongoDB with Mongoose and running into some issues. Have MongoDB running in a terminal window and created a file called cat.js to practice DB creation. Installed mongoose and created the following file:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:3000/cat_app", {useNewUrlParser: true});

var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String, 
  age: Number,
  temperament: String
});
```

Get the following error when I try to run node `cat.js`

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/danieluribe/Databases/cat.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:596:3)
```

I was told that by simply using mongoose.connect and specifying localhost and database name, the database would be created, however, when I check Mongod, there is nothing.

Comment: How you run? and please show `cat.js` file content

Comment: I'm running using `node cat.js`.  The file is the first set of code above.

Comment: Do you have `package.json` file?

Comment: I do not. Let me run npm init.

Comment: Created package.json, still not working.

Comment: It's weird. If you run from the directory `cat.js` exists, there should be no error. Even from other paths

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195416/discussion-between-fancy-daniel-and-ebrahim-pasbani).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to export module with :
module.exports = mongoose.model("Cat", catSchema)